# How to find embedded Coordinate Reference system in a Layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to find CRS in an added shapefile. 
Ex. In ArcGIS if we go to Layer Properties and Source we can find embedded CRS to a layer.

How to find in QGIS, embedded CRS in a layer/ Shapefile?

I think in QGIS, if we move to Layer properties and General, it doesn't show extract CRS of layer.

*Because I Added shapefile with undefined CRS. In that case it shows EPSG:32244 - WGS 72 / UTM zone 44N. But I added undefined one????*

I'm using qgis 1.7.4,
System is Windows 7

**How to find in QGIS, embedded CRS in a layer/ Shapefile???**

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the system defaulting to a global coordinate value without a Prj file to tell it what it should be defined as. Your best option is to create a Prj with what coordinate system and projection you want it to have.